# Yesod book example chat and scaffolding

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm trying to make the chat example from the [Yesod book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491915595) working in the scaffolding site.

I think I've corrected almost all I had to correct, but all of that is completely new to me (it's my first "real" Haskell project) and I'm not very confident in all my modifications; moreover, I'm really stuck at the point 7. Could you comment all the following points if necessary, and helping me for the 7. (in **bold** some questions/remarks)?

1. Copy/paste the Chat.hs and Chat/Data.hs in the root of my site,
2. add `import Chat as Import` and `import Chat.Data as Import` to Import.NoFoundation,
3. add import of IO, Bool, return, Maybe(Nothing), ($) in Data.hs, since the extension NoImplicitPrelude is on **Seems very clumsy... Do we have to import all the standard operators on each new file?**
4. in Fundation.hs, add `getChat` in the `App` record (after `appHttpManager` and `appLogger`)
5. in Fundation.hs, add YesodChat instance for App: I had to modify the `getUserName` on the `Just uid` case (in the original example of Chat, it was just `Just uid -> return uid`):

   ```
           Just uid -> do
           muser <- runDB  $ get uid
           case muser of
               Nothing -> error "uid not in the DB"
               Just user ->  return $ userIdent user
   ```

   **This seems very long and nested... Can we do better?**
6. In `Fundation.hs`, add `chatWidget ChatR` after the line `pc <-  widgetToPageContent $ do` in the `defaultLayout` definition.
7. Now, I have the following warning :

   ```
   Application.hs:60:36: Warning:

   Fields of ‘App’ not initialised: getChat
   In the expression: App {..}
   ```

   I think I have to write something like `getChat <- newChan >>=Chat` after the `appLogger <- newStdoutLoggerSet defaultBufSize >>= makeYesodLogger` and `appStatic <- ...` in the `makeFundation` definition, but the type doesn't match. **I'm a totally lost here, I don't really understand how this function `makeFundation` works.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually got almost the entire way there. I think you just need to change the line to:

```
getChat <- fmap Chat newChan
```

Alternatively, if you're not familiar with he `fmap` function yet, you can use do notation and get:

```
chan <- newChan
let getChat = Chat chan
```